# How to run Docker on an external USB hard-drive in Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: docker

I am trying to run the following command in Ubuntu 21.10 with Docker so that it will run on my external USB hard-drive:

```
sudo docker run -v /media/alexanderjsingleton/SEAGATE/blockchain -P registry.gitlab.com/pulsechaincom/go-pulse --datadir=/media/alexanderjsingleton/SEAGATE/blockchain --pulsechain-testnet
```

Evidently, I need to configure some Docker settings in order for this occur, in addition to mounting the drive, because whenever I run the above command the files are downloaded and saved within the Docker directory on my computer instead of the external USB hard-drive- can anyone please advise?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using the -v option, you need to specify the source and destination, separated with a colon. e.g.

```
docker run -v /path/to/your/usb/filesystem:/path/inside/container ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  So according to your answer above, if the Docker container files are located within /var/lib/docker, that should be appended after the colon?

Comment: /var/lib/docker is used by docker to store various files by default. Usually you don't want to present that to any container. The -v option takes 2 paths, separated by a colon. The first one is the path on the host computer where you run docker. The second one is where you want that to mount inside your container.

Comment: How does this look? `docker run -v /media/alexanderjsingleton/SEAGATE/blockchain:/blockchain -P registry.gitlab.com/pulsechaincom/go-pulse --datadir=/blockchain --pulsechain-testnet`